# Ajax callback onstart works even if input is invalid

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

I have input fields and a command button inside an `<h:form>`. The input fields are required, and the validation error messages are showing well if something invalid is entered. At the end of the form, I have the following button:

```
<p:commandButton value="" ajax="true" update="foormm"
    icon="ui-icon-check" actionListener="#{bean.sayHello}"
    onstart="dialog.show()"
    oncomplete="handleAjaxResponse(xhr, status, args)">
</p:commandButton>
```

The problem is, the dialog is showing regardless of validation. I thought the Ajax request was made iff inputs are validated. What's wrong here? Why does `onstart` get triggered even though the required fields are empty?

I use JSF 2.0, Primefaces 3.0 and Weblogic 12.1 with Eclipse.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: The dialog is supposed say "Wait, request being processed". So it'd meaningless to show it onsuccess since the user would have waited already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In other words, you want to show the dialog only when no validation errors have occurred after the postback? The `onstart` doesn't take that into account at all. It's invoked right before the ajax postback is invoked.

You'd need to approach it differently. The `<p:dialog>` has a `visible` attribute which can take an EL expression evaluating to a `boolean` outcome. You could make use of it:

```html
<p:dialog id="dialog" visible="#{some condition}">
```

The `#{some condition}` can at its simplest be a combination of [`FacesContext#isPostback()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#isPostback%28%29) and [`FacesContext#isValidationFalied()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#isValidationFailed%28%29). So, if it's a postback and the validation has not failed, then the dialog should be visible.

```html
<p:dialog id="dialog" visible="#{facesContext.postback and not facesContext.validationFailed}">
```

You just have to let your button update that dialog as well:

```html
<p:commandButton value="" ajax="true" update="foormm dialog"
    icon="ui-icon-check" actionListener="#{bean.sayHello}"
    oncomplete="handleAjaxResponse(xhr, status, args)">
</p:commandButton>
```

Alternatively, you can also let the dialog's `visible` condition depend on some bean property which you set in the action(listener?) method:

```html
<p:dialog id="dialog" visible="#{bean.saidHello}">
```